# Is the Worklight WL.Server.InvokeProcedure method executed as a network call?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

When I use the server side API in an adapter and I use `WL.Server.InvokeProcedure`,
Is it executed as a network call? or does it invoke the adapter directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WL.Server.InvokeProcedure` invokes the adapter directly. The adapter in turn uses HTTClient to open a network call with the backend (when `WL.Server.invokeHttp` is used within it).